# Is there any application for Java like "Tour de Flex" for Flex 4 which provides samples for Java6?

Tags: java, flexbuilder

Do you know any software like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Sun's [A Visual Guide to Swing Components](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/features/components.html). It's only a static web page but gives an idea of the components and what they look like.

Answer (score 1):

For JavaFX download [Java SE Development Kit Demos and Samples](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

The Ensemble8 demo is very similar to Tour de Flex but for JavaFX...

This demo is available in both source and executable .jar form.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a general purpose language and it has many different farmeworks that may look or resemlbe Flex e.g. JavaFX, Java Applets, GWT, even JSP/JSF based solutions that reuse a lot of Web 2.0 stuff etc.

Here are some links:

http://javafx.com/samples/

http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCheckBox

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's JDK contains a demo folder, but is not exhaustive.